# Any way to generate elements faster and check if they are prime?

Tags: c++, variable-assignment

I have an assignment and here is the requierment

```
Write a program that finds the number of the prime numbers in a randomly 
generated row.

No more than 100 examples are set to the standard input. Each 
example is defined by two positive integers s and N per row (s <10^3, N <10^9). 
s sets a numerical row (by srand (s)) of length N, which is generated with 
rand ()% 1000.

Print out the count of all prime numbers.
```

I currently have this as my code which on my PC for the maximum values takes 3 seconds to find the count of all prime numbers in the numerical row.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

bool isPrime(int num) {
   if (num <= 3) {
     return num > 1;
 } else if (num % 2 == 0 || num % 3 == 0) {
    return false;
 } else {
     for (int i = 5; i * i <= num; i += 6) {
         if (num % i == 0 || num % (i + 2) == 0) {
             return false;
         }
     }
     return true;
 }
}

int main()
{
int seed;

long long lenght;

while(cin >> seed >> lenght){

    srand(seed);

    unsigned long long totalPrimes = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < lenght; ++i) {

        int prime = rand() % 1000;

        if (isPrime(prime)) {
            totalPrimes++;
        }
    }

    cout << totalPrimes << endl;

    int seed = 0;

    int lenght = 0;

 }


 return 0;
}
```

The problem is this doesn't seem to be fast enough as he wants it. Is there some faster way? I have tried multiple things and all are slower than my code above.

Comment: Computing the same prime numbers over and over again in `isPrime` is time-waster. Look up the Sieve of Eratosthenes.  Use the sieve to compute all primes < 1000 and store the result in a `std::set`. Keep a count of all input numbers that are in the `std::set.`

Comment: Reviewing working code is probably better posted on: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make an algorithmic improvements

"All programming is an exercise in caching."
-Terje Mathisen

so why calculate the primes more than once, just store them and see if the generated random numbers are one of them, either by linear search or binary search.

If you run through all numbers once to find primes and store the in an index array so you can make the lookup in O(1) instead of O(log N)

```
if (primeList[x])
  totalPrimes++;
```

Comment: I don't think going over all the 168 prime numbers that are between 0 and 1000 would be a good idea for each number. That way you have to check a lot more than my function isPrime() which only takes at most 4 steps. Maybe you have an example? I have tried binary search and it's slower.

Comment: @BorislavKirilov I think you will be surprised how fast it can be compared to all the '%' you else need to do. I'll update my answer as I remember an even faster method.